# При попытке запуска приложения вылетает org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Я нашел похожие ошибки в интернете, но советы из ответов либо мало помогли, либо пришлось бы переделать все под связь OneToMany, что мне делать не желательно

Полный текст ошибки
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.spring.config.DataConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKbu6ivurs2s4v3x3yvbj632dwx:user_roles [role_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (user_roles [user_id,role_id])

Сущности

User.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<UserRole> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
//getters, setters, constructors
```

Role.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
@Transient
public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "role", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleSet")
    private Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<>();
//getters, setters, constructors
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Все остальные классы вроде как реализованы верно, но на всякий случай [ссылка на Git-репозиторий](https://github.com/relizerel/Spring-Security.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на ваш класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
@Transient
public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "role", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roleSet")
    private Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<>();
```

А потом эту же таблицу вы описываете как

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<UserRole> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
```

В первом варианте вы описали `user_roles`с полями `id` и `name`, а в `User.java` вы описываете эту таблицу с полями `user_id` и `role_id`. На что вам `Hibernate` вполне объяснимо бросает следующую ошибку: `"Foreign key ... user_roles [role_id]..."` Он просто не знает на что ссылается `role_id`.

Решение: вам необходимо описывать в `Role.java` не таблицу связей `user_roles` (достаточно того, что вы описали ее в аннотации), а таблицу `role`. То есть заменить название таблицы `@Table(name = "role")`или как у вас называется таблица с ролями

Comment: Сперва вы описываете модели, например `user` и `role`. А посредством `@ManyToMany` связь между ними

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Я ошибся на одну букву в названии таблицы. И, соответственно, ссылался на несуществующую таблицу.

Comment: @АлексейГумилев, у всех бывает)

Comment: Буду благодарен. если подскажете, почему тогда у меня заработал код в моем ответе? Ведь он все-равно был не правильным. И дальше, при попытке обратиться к сущностям я получал ошибку. Я просто смотрел на примеры, в которых указываются FetchType и делал сначала с использованием FetchType, а потом наткнулся на CascadeType, но в том примере нет объяснений того, как это работает

Comment: Я думаю, это связано с тем, что вы убрали `FetchType.EAGER`. По умолчанию стоит ленивая загрузка и, возможно, `Hibernate` просто принял как факт вашу связь `@ManyToMany`. А уже  когда вы попробовали обратится напрямую к сущностям, он просто не смог

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Изменение кода в сущности User с

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

на

```java
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
```

исправило данную ошибку (но теперь появилась куча других, эх)

Comment: вопрос сложно считать закрытым, вы ведь не понимаете `@ManyToMany`

Comment: @azlov и без вас это знал. или вы хотите помочь разобраться более досконально?)

Comment: возможно не досконально, но чтобы вы понимали как работает